# How do I translate a .htaccess file to Firebase hosting config?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, firebase-hosting

I've built an SPA in Angular 2, and I'm hosting it on Firebase Hosting.
I have built som extra static html pages specifically for crawl bots (since they do not read updated dynamic html, only the initial index.html) and now I need to rewrite the URL for HTTP requests from bots to these static pages.

I know how to do this in a `.htaccess` file, but I can't figure out how to translate the rewrite conditions in my `firebase.json` file.

This is my `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
 
# Remove trailing /
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
 
# Rewrite spiders to static html
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (googlebot|bingbot|msnbot|yahoo|Baidu|aolbuild|facebookexternalhit|iaskspider|DuckDuckBot|Applebot|Almaden|iarchive|archive.org_bot) [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/static%{REQUEST_URI}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /static/$1.html [L]
 
# Rewrite spiders to static index.html
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (googlebot|bingbot|msnbot|yahoo|Baidu|aolbuild|facebookexternalhit|iaskspider|DuckDuckBot|Applebot|Almaden|iarchive|archive.org_bot) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "^/$"
RewriteRule ^ /static/index.html [L]
 
# If an existing asset or directory is requested, serve it
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
 
# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use the Angular app entry point
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

I've read Firebase's docs on [Configuring Rewrites](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrites), but can't figure out how to target a specific User Agent.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebase Hosting doesn't support configuring rewrites based on the user-agent header. It can support rewrites based on the path, and [rewrites based on the language of the user/browser](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/i18n-rewrites).

The only option I know of to rewrite based on other headers, is to [connect Firebase Hosting to Cloud Functions or Cloud Run](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/serverless-overview) and do the rewrite in code. But this is a significantly different exercise than configuring rewrites in the `firebase.json` file, so I recommend reading up on it before choosing this path.

Comment: I just wanted to see if there was a change to this, trying to find a better solution for social sharing so when Facebook or twitter try to read a url